# How to create Manual ID CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have a Json file as such :

```
{
   "_id":"03f8dcb28c93ec4b6c39d6bdf45bcf57",
   "api_rev":"1.0",
   "type":"router"
}
```

The _id identifies a particular entity thus, i will not like to go for the auto generated one.
When i push to couchdb i get :

```
{"error":"POST uses auto generated id"}
```

How may i force the id i provide as the actual id without using the auto generated type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a PUT request instead to create the document with `PUT /database/03f8dcb28c93ec4b6c39d6bdf45bcf57` and have the body as:

```
{
   "api_rev":"1.0",
   "type":"router"
}
```

That will create a new document with that id.